# CSS Div Boxes that are centred and arrange according to browser window size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a web page that has multiple amount of Div (.collectionbox) boxes that are identical to each other and 'float' next to each other as much as they can until they hit the side of the window then start a new line. So if i was to create a PHP loops it will all still look centered and the mroe divs the longer the bage would become.

Within each div (.collectionbox) is another div (.addtobasket) box that needs to sit at the bottom of the div (.collectionbox).

All of these sit inside of one main div (#mainbody)

Ive managed to get everything i want working individually, but getting it all working together is causing me head aches.

Currently my code below will center the page as needed, now i would just like the .collectionbox divs to have the same effect a float: left. would have without actually being to the left and for the .addtobasket div to be at the bottom of the .collectionbox regardless of the contents.

My CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#mainbody {
width: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.collectionbox {
height: 295px;
width: 295px;
background-image: url(collectionbox.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
text-align: left;
position: relative;
float: none;
}

.addtobasket {
width: 266px;
text-align: center;
height: 57px;
position: relative;
left: 16px;
top: 50px;
}
</style>
```

My Html:

```
<div id="mainbody">

<div class="collectionbox">
<div class=".collectionboxtitle"><img src="title-verybritish.png" width="295" height="49" /></div>
<div class="addtobasket"><img src="price-4-99.png" width="174" height="57" border="0"/></div>
<p>Test</p>
</div> 

<div class="collectionbox">
<div class=".collectionboxtitle"><img src="title-verybritish.png" width="295" height="49" /></div>
<div class="addtobasket"><img src="price-4-99.png" width="174" height="57" border="0"/></div>
<p>Test </p>
</div> 

<div class="collectionbox">
<div class=".collectionboxtitle"><img src="title-verybritish.png" width="295" height="49" /></div>
<div class="addtobasket"><img src="price-4-99.png" width="174" height="57" border="0"/></div>
<p>Test</p>
</div> 

<div class="collectionbox">
<div class=".collectionboxtitle"><img src="title-verybritish.png" width="295" height="49" /></div>
<div class="addtobasket"><img src="price-4-99.png" width="174" height="57" border="0"/></div>
<p>Test </p>
</div> 

</div>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the boxes (`collectionbox`) centered and still displayed in a row next to eachother you can use display: `inline-block` instead of `float: left`.

```
 .collectionbox {
    height: 295px;
    width: 295px;
    background-image: url(collectionbox.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

As for the `addtobasket` div you should absolute position it to make it stay att the bottom of it's parent at all times.

```
.addtobasket {
    width: 266px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 57px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/usK87/)

Comment: Worked a treat! Thank you very much :)